# Covering and Heine-Borel theorem

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, compactness

I am studying complex integration on [https://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-Springer-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1852337338/ref=sr_1_12?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1537368776&sr=1-12&keywords=Complex+analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1852337338)

The author states that the Heine-Borel theorem is needed for some proofs later and then explain the concept of open covering of $S \subset \mathbb C$ as a "possibly infinite collection of open sets $V_i$ whose union contains S".

Then the Heine-Borel theorem: "let $S$ be a closed, bounded subset of $\mathbb C$. Then every open covering of $S$ contains a finite subcovering of $S$."

I can follow the proof, but my intuition clashes with it. Why does S need to be closed? The only reason i can come with is if the definition of covering is incomplete and the $V_i$ need to be subset of $S$. Is that so?

Comment: Any compact subspace of a Hausdorff space must be closed.

Comment: Please, don't answer with topology. I know only calculus and linear algebra

Comment: Consider the $S = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1 \}$. Define $T(x,y):= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : x < |z| < y \}$. Note that clearly $T$ is closed for all $x,y$ with $0 < x < y$. 

Now take consider this open covering of $\displaystyle S \subset T(0, .5) \cup T(.49, .75) \cup T(.70, .87) \cup T(.85, .90) \cup \cdots$. Good luck trying to find an finite subcover for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be closed because otherwise the statement is false. If $S$ is not closed and if $z\in\overline S\setminus S$, consider the set$$\left\{\left\{w\in\mathbb{C}\,\middle|\,\lvert w-z\rvert>\frac1n\right\}\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}.$$It is an open cover of $S$, but it you can check that it has no finite subcover.